# Using position:fixed to delete white spaces. Conflicting with other elements

Tags: css

in my page I'll have two divs like this

```
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height: 100px;">

</div>

<div>
     something!
</div>
```

My problem is that the "something" div doesn't take the first div's height in
consideration and comes under it. When I delete the **position:fixed;** off everything goes back to normal.

Thanks.

Comment: That's because the divs are behaving exactly like you told them to. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the first div which is the header to be containing all the top space of the page. And the second div to be simply under it.

Comment: Don't set position fixed then

Comment: My problem was that white space that only disappear if I use position:fixed; . I just solved this but deleting that line and setting body{ margin:0;}

Comment: Consider letting me know if my answer helped by ticking it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you need to use `position:absolute` or `position:relative` instead. Making a `fixed` div makes it independent of other divs as it is a fixed element regardless.

Example:

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height: 100px; background-color:red;">
header
</div>

<div>
...
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score -2):

make second div with padding-top:100px

```
<div style="position:fixed;width:100%;height: 100px;">

</div>

<div style="padding-top:100px">
 something!
</div>
```

Comment: That's like fixing your busted car by building a lorry around it.